# infer types per key to multiple mapping objects/types

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typescript-generics

I am wondering how to create generic type mappings.

As you can see on the image and/or in the playground..

The code "runs" fine, but the typings are somehow weird/mixed.

Imagine there is even another mapping to a Subject, so I want to be able to do something like this, type-safe of course, .. :

```typescript
subjMap[key].next(accessorMap[key]());
```

Is this even possible with different objects/maps.. Or do I need to create one object per "key" so to say..?

```typescript
type KeyToTypeMapping = {
    iaModel: string;
    debug: boolean;
};

type MappingKeys = keyof KeyToTypeMapping;

type KeyToTypedAccessor<T> = Record<keyof T, () => T[keyof T]>;

const accessorMap: KeyToTypedAccessor<KeyToTypeMapping> = {
    iaModel: () => "string",
    debug: () => true
};

const stringResult = accessorMap.iaModel();

// TS tells me that the type of `stringResult` is string | boolean
console.log(stringResult);

type KeyToTypedFn<T> = {
    [Key in keyof T]: { next: (_: T[Key]) => void };
};

// here is another map with the same keys and "base-types"..
// .. there could be even more ..
const subjMap: KeyToTypedFn<KeyToTypeMapping> = {
    iaModel: { next: (_) => { console.log('next', _); } },
    debug: { next: (_) => { console.log('next', _); } },
}

Object.keys(accessorMap).forEach(k => {
    // sadly we need to cast here..
    const typedKey = k as keyof KeyToTypeMapping;

    const val = accessorMap[typedKey]();

    // here TS complains that val (type of string | boolean) is not assignable to never ..
    subjMap[typedKey].next(val);
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're looking for a [mapped type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html#handbook-content), which would look like this:

```typescript
type KeyToTypedAccessor<T> = {
    [Key in keyof T]: () => T[Key];
};
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBA0hIBUD2DwQLIEMxgJYDsBzKAXigG8AoKGqXTdJAEwgBsAuKAZ2ACcDCAbmq0WAIwCuhTmKRJWETPmEBfYZVCRY8ZKkhMAggGMjELlyS8APAgB8pCiJoBtOCDr4oAa3hIAZlAIALqcABQAlKT2CK7wQarqRkj4PFCYJmYWvFhgnG66aIYZ5pZW+ShoOXhE9mRUtHQMzGxhkST2AEQ8-EQdADROUOJSrVFQfBIQlGqUlEkpwNx8AgBKZhKsi2TppiXZ2AB09IwsrBHCAPQXDQB6APxzyamy8or4a1wbW2nFWTkHw0I50oV1uD0eKVeB1YSCB3VW6024WEQA)

Full Example:

```typescript
type KeyToTypeMapping = {
    iaModel: string;
    debug: boolean;
};

type KeyToTypedAccessor<T> = {
    [Key in keyof T]: () => T[Key];
};

const accessorMap: KeyToTypedAccessor<KeyToTypeMapping> = {
    iaModel: () => "string",
    debug: () => true
};

const stringResult = accessorMap.iaModel();
//    ^? −−−− string
const booleanResult = accessorMap.debug();
//    ^? −−−− boolean

console.log(stringResult);
```

---

In a comment you said you were stuck at this point:

```typescript
Object.keys(accessorMap).forEach(k => {
    // sadly we need to cast here..
    const typedKey = k as keyof KeyToTypeMapping;

    const val = accessorMap[typedKey]();

    // here TS complains that val (type of string | boolean) is not assignable to never ..
    subjMap[typedKey].next(val);
});
```

Unfortunately, you can't fix that in a typesafe way without doing something so that TypeScript knows either:

1. **Which** key of `KeyToTypeMapping` `typedKey` is, so it knows what the value type is. It could be either (`iaModel` leading to a string value, or `debug` leading to a boolean value).

   or
2. That the **same** `KeyToTypeMapping` key is being used both for indexing into `subjMap` and `accessorMap`.

#1 leads to some fairly ugly repetitive code, so we don't want that (in this case).

Re #2, you'd think TypeScript would know from your code (or the even-more-obvious `subjMap[typedKey].next(accessorMap[typedKey]();`) that the key is the same, but it wants a generic function to help it:

```typescript
function setNext<Key extends keyof KeyToTypeMapping>(
    subjMap: KeyToTypedFn<KeyToTypeMapping>,
    accessorMap: KeyToTypedAccessor<KeyToTypeMapping>,
    key: Key,
) {
    subjMap[key].next(accessorMap[key]());
}
```

Then we can do:

```typescript
Object.keys(accessorMap).forEach((key) => {
    // (As you say, you're stuck with the type assertion on `key`.)
    setNext(subjMap, accessorMap, key as any as keyof KeyToTypeMapping);
});
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBA0hIBUD2DwQLIEMxgJYDsBzKAXigG8AoKGqXTdJAEwgBsAuKAZ2ACcDCAbmq0WAIwCuhTmKRJWETPmEBfYZVCRY8ZKkhMAggGMjELlyS8APAgB8pCiJoBtOCDr4oAa3hIAZlAIALqcABQAlKT2CK7wQarqRkj4PFCYJmYWvFhgnG66aIYZ5pZW+ShoOXhE9mRUtHQMzGxhkST2AEQ8-EQdADROUOJSrVFQfBIQlGqUlEkpwNx8AgBKZhKsi2TppiXZ2AB09IwsrBHCAPQXDQB6APxzyamy8or4a1wbW2nFWTkHw0I50oV1uD0eKVeB1YSCB3VW6024XUmmg5T0ECYADF8DZao4GrF3ARvL4AsFOOQoPgIAAPYBhAD6nBibiCbXsADckLgmFAZjMIalPmIAFY5PI6Cr6HFlKUYqoCfH1WjHZocCjUukMqChRkczXzCwKaGw0IAchp9PNfSg+sE-P5AwagMpWvpTINVKNUJhQMt2ptduRjpUA0Ffgk+CMwFwyW4EGAADltXL3NqIPgmFxSSB-NpENKMNhqoRbKFBiLxdhJYWMdjcejKiWlc7aDtMpYJQWCvpjLssmne8WcK3Bj4QLWBpEVTQqzlnBOggcrcBQh29gulxFkdNZgB5MUQGMHCdcde-LvYcIHPyWACi6QAFqFQhOvYNQaEDDm8xJuJgIC2n+5q8NAPASEYXhQAA7rgwBPuMT7QKiaTmBAvCxvG8YAAYTjhBzhJWiYpvSoTztgtobn8lG5mhaT4O4mA5hO+ZNpAipELuKi7kAA)

---

(Side note: Type assertions aren't casts. A *cast* [in languages that have them] can actually convert a value from one thing to another, for instance converting a two's complement `int` bit pattern to a IEEE-754 double-precision floating point `double` bit pattern with an equivalent or near-equivalent numeric value despite the fact the bit patterns for [say] `42` are very different between those two formats. TypeScript's type assertions never do any kind of conversion. They don't even exist at runtime. So they're just assertions, just you telling TypeScript "trust me, this ? is an X." :-) )

Comment: great, that puts me one step further! updated my question.. now there is the second problem regarding your question (commented above) :)

Comment: @slaesh - I've updated the answer to help with that part.

Comment: I was afraid of the answer, but so I need to stick with it.. ;) thanks!! good explanation of that side note btw. knew that, but its easier to say "cast" instead of "type assertion" :P but for sure, in the next PR I will write "do we really need that type assertion?" ;)

Comment: @slaesh - :-D I find the distinction helpful just for myself mentally. When I'm programming in languages with casts, I'm not too bothered about them (depending on the cast of course) But with type assertions I'm always "Hmmmm. Am I **really** sure this is true?" (And when the answer is no, I write an assertion function. It's amusing how often my answer is "no, I'm not that sure." :-D )

Comment: yeah! :) that's true. in these "no, I am not that sure"-cases, we do work a lot with type-guards. and if it's not the expected type, we throw a "meaningful error" or are trying to recover somehow... :)

Answer (score 2):

Just don't use Record so you can access the key directly !

```
type KeyToTypeMapping = {
    iaModel: string;
    debug: boolean;
};

type KeyToTypedAccessor<T> = { [P in keyof T]: () => T[P] }

declare const accessorMap: KeyToTypedAccessor<KeyToTypeMapping>

const stringResult = accessorMap.iaModel();
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/FAFwngDgpgBA0lMAVA9kyUCyBDCECWAdgOYwC8MA3sDLTPtpigCZQA2AXDAM4gBORYgG4adVgCMArsS7iUKNlGyERAXxGgM8RKnTRmAQQDGRqN24o+AHiQA+clRgBtAAr1CMANaIUAMxhIALpcABQAlOT2SK6BMKrAwKxGbNh8sEYohLww2CZmFnw4EFwIyGgYhnnmllaluhhFBCS2CRlZIDz8ggBKZpJsHRS5ptWFuAB0DEysbOEawG0WiuNsKMQhvAIkvdz9IGEiQA)

Comment: thanks @Matthieu!! just stumbled across the next stone.. updated my answer :)